# Doctrine does not map its own generated entity

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

I'm trying to learn Doctrine.

I'm trying to update my database with the last generated entity.

I generated the entity with doctrine:generate:entity

here it is:

```
<?php

namespace NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Lasttest
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Lasttest
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Lasttest
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}


?>
```

So basic stuff, I did not change anything.

Then I'd like doctrine to generate the table in my sql database but here is the answer to:

doctrine:mapping:info -> you do not have any mapped entity

doctrine:schema:update -> you do not have metadata class to process

doctrine:generate:entities RandomnameBundle -> does not contain any mapped entities

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not exactly found the problem but it's solved

-> I have updated Symfony to its last version

Answer (score 2):

Try changing doctrine orm mapping from auto_mapping to manual.
Example shown below:

```
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
       ...
       auto_mapping: true
```

TO

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                NRtworks\ChartOfAccountsBundle: ~
```

Comment: I have tried but it does not change anything

In another bundle I have another class which I built on my own, then created the sql table on my own too, and I can persist data into it. But same problem there I cannot generate or update the scheme

Comment: I just tried xml, yml & php (deleting everything each time) and mapping:info always is empty...

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-table

@ORM\Table requires table name.

> Required attributes:
>
> name: Name of the table

Comment: I have thought about that, I tried it but it does not change anything.